# How to solve $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}\sum_{k=0}^{59}{100 \choose k}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Part of an exercise, I got the following sum:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{100}\sum_{k=0}^{59}{100 \choose k}
$$
I'm trying to evaluate it and get the answer. What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: It is 59 or 50.

Comment: @ZAhmed It's 59. I know that the answer should be around $~0.028$.

Comment: $$\frac{153949198576920363674795555347}{158456325028528675187087900672}\approx 0.97$$

Answer (score 2):

Take it as a joke (but the answer is correct)
$$\frac 1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{n}{k}=1-\frac { \binom{n}{p+1}}{2^n} \, _2F_1(1,p-n+1;p+2;-1)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function.

Back to serious, as @Buraian answered, you cannot do much (except using Wolfram Alpha !!).

Answer (score 1):

You *could* reduce the number of binomial coefficients you need to calculate by using:

$$\frac12\binom{100}{50}+\sum_{k=0}^{49}\binom{100}{k} = \frac12\sum_{k=0}^{100}\binom{100}k = 2^{99}$$

hence:

$$\left(\frac12\right)^{100}\sum_{k=0}^{59}\binom{100}k=\frac12+\left(\frac12\right)^{100}\left(\frac12\binom{100}{50}+\sum_{k=51}^{59}\binom{100}k\right)$$

so you "only" need to calculate $10$ of them.

Answer (score 0):

$$ ( \binom{100}{0} + \binom{100}{1} ) + ( \binom{100}{2} + \binom{100}{3} ) ... + ( \binom{100}{58} + \binom{100}{59} )$$

$$ =\binom{101}{1} + \binom{101}{3} + \binom{101}{5}...\binom{101}{59}$$

Not much better you can do than this I Think, there is no closed form for the above acc. to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#cite_note-7)